# Downgrading from IE6 to IE5?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, windows-2000

How do I revert back to Internet Explorer 5 on Windows 2000 Professional, if I updated it to Internet Explorer 6 via microsoft automatic updates?

Before people ask why I want to do this and why am I still on Windows 2000, I need to do this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can give this program a shot:
It seems that you may even test with more than just IE 5

[Multiple_IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)

Comment: I have used this program for testing as we thought it would be important to have all versions compliant. It took too long and I gave up but the point is, the software you suggest is great! +1

Answer (score 0):

I have read many posts on this and it seems difficult but some have managed to do it. If IE6 came pre-installed then you're stuck with it, but as it is you should be OK since you upgraded.

You could try to run this command and hope it works: w2kexcp.exe /u

Or, in control panel's add/remove programs show hidden.

[A suggestion from here](http://inetexplorer.mvps.org/answers/8.html) :

```
Open C:\Program files\Internet Explorer.
Right click the folder Uninstall information.
Click Properties
Uncheck the hidden mode and press OK.
Go to C:\Program files\Internet Explorer\Setup.
Run setup.exe
```

And lastly, this [software can do it for 2000 and XP](http://www.litepc.com/xplite.html)